# No grub screen is shown

Tags: grub2, windows-7

Have installed Ubuntu and windows 7.But now while booting system boots via windows and no grub screen is seen.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the grub menu the following way:
You use Escape key after UEFI screen but before grub normally shows.
Or if BIOS you press an hold shift key from BIOS screen until grub menu loads

If windows is booting first I suspect that grub may not have been install properly.

Comment: It is not possible to reinstall Ubuntu or windows since important files are in Ubuntu.Also the user is not aware of the Ubuntu version which was installed. Is there any way to get the Ubuntu back....

Comment: You do not need to reinstall Ubuntu just Grub boot loader.  #1 below has a link as to how to do that

Answer (score 0):

Installing windows after ubuntu will overwrite GRUB with windows boot loader.

As long as I know, there is two ways to deal with that:

#### 1 - Reinstall GRUB after the windows installation

There are many ways to repair GRUB, as recommended on the [official ubuntu help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Installing#Fixing_a_Broken_System)

#### 2 - Set the windows entry inactive

Like [Kana mentioned here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/242219/355168), is possible to set the Windows boot manager entry to inactive, as Windows overwrites the entry to 0000 and changes the boot order.

As [Karlovsky120 also reminded](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/547371/355168) it may only work if Ubuntu has been installed in UEFI mode. You can check it using the command: `if test -d /sys/firmware/efi;then echo efi;else echo bios;fi`.

The links mentioned already contains all the information that you need bring GRUB back. But if you need extra help, leave a comment and I can try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

I just detached the harf disk and connected another harddisk having Ubuntu and booted it.After booting I shut down the system and connected the old harddisk again.Now Ubuntu is booting and windows is not booting